# Classical meaning of 為 at the time of the Daodejing

Tags: translation

I’m very curious 無為 should be translated. I recently heard that the usage of the word was “fake” at the time of writing the Daodejing

Comment: What you are saying is partially correct ([段玉裁《说文解字注》](https://ctext.org/wiki.pl?if=gb&chapter=719694): 經傳多假為為偽), but at least for Daodejing I have never heard of a serious attempt to explain 無為 as 無偽.

Answer (score 0):

There are two schools about "無為(inaction/do nothing)" in Chinese culture:

1. Taoism - 道家思想, 指要依天命,  顺其自然, 没必要有所作为 - The Daoist doctrine of inaction, letting things take their own course.
2. Confusism - 儒家指掌政者應無為而治, 用德政感化人民. (此處"無為"指不增添擾民苛/鎖政) - The Confucian doctrine of inaction, the government should not burden the people (under its ruling) with tedious unreasonable policies.

Note:  "为"字，古代与"伪"相通。"无为"即"无伪"。伪字主要有两个含义："人为"和"虚假"。https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A0%E4%B8%BA_(%E9%81%93%E5%AE%B6)#